# Load more GitHub user followers with API

Tags: jquery, ajax, github-api

I'm playing around with the **GitHub API** and trying to build a simple app that lets you search for a GitHub user which then returns a list of that user's followers. I'm currently displaying the first 100 followers and would like each button click to load the next batch of 100 followers until all followers have been returned.

Since I'm loading the max count displayed on each page (100), I can access the second page by including '&page=2' at the end of the url. I just don't know how to automatically load each new page until there are no more followers to load.

Any advice on how to accomplish this? Any help is much appreciated.

```
// Make request to Github
$.ajax({
  url:'https://api.github.com/users/'+username,
  data:{
    client_id:'9ecc0f206ecd34f2f552',
    client_secret:'6eee17df91630a531ea2acf49848dec408079e9c'
  }
}).done(function(user){
  $.ajax({
    url:'https://api.github.com/users/'+username+'/followers?per_page=100',
    data:{
      client_id:'9ecc0f206ecd34f2f552',
      client_secret:'6eee17df91630a531ea2acf49848dec408079e9c'
    }
  }).done(function(followers){
    $.each(followers, function(index, follower){
      $('#followers').append(`
        <div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">
            <img class="follower-avatar" src="${follower.avatar_url}" alt="" />
            <p>${follower.login}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a href="${follower.html_url}" target="_blank" class="btn">View profile</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      `);
    });
  });
  $('#profile').html(`
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <img  src="${user.avatar_url}">
            <div>
                <h3>${user.name}</h3>
            </div>
            <a target="_blank" class="btn" href="${user.html_url}">View Profile</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-9">
          <div>
            <h1>Followers</h1> <br/>
            <p>${user.followers}</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h1>Followers</h1> <br/>
            <p>2313123</p>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="page-header">${user.name}'s followers</h3>
    <div id="followers"></div>
  `);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a recursive function, we can continue requesting further pages of followers.

I moved some of your code into a function below called `getFollowers` that accepts a `page` number as a parameter. It's initially called with the page as `1`, and if we notice that the AJAX result has the same number of rows as users we requested per page (i.e. our `per_page` is 100 and page 1 had 100 users), it's worth checking to see if there's a next page.

Then the function is called recursively with `page` incremented by 1. This will continue running until all of the pages are loaded (or your API rate limit is exceeded!).

Let me know if you have any questions.

(For demonstration purposes I found a random GitHub user with a moderate number of followers.)

**EDIT:** Per your comment and initial request, I've updated the code below to require a click of a button to load the next page.

```js
var username = 'cartazio';
var nextPage;

// bind click event for button
$('#load').on('click', function() {
  getFollowers(nextPage);
});

// getFollowers function with one parameter - current page
function getFollowers(page) {

  // how many followers per page to retrieve
  perPage = 100;

  // update next page global variable
  nextPage = page + 1;

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.github.com/users/' + username + '/followers?per_page=' + perPage + '&page=' + page,
    data: {
      client_id: '9ecc0f206ecd34f2f552',
      client_secret: '6eee17df91630a531ea2acf49848dec408079e9c'
    }
  }).done(function(followers) {
    $.each(followers, function(index, follower) {
      $('#followers').append(`
            <div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                <img class="follower-avatar" src="${follower.avatar_url}" alt="" />
                <p>${follower.login}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <a href="${follower.html_url}" target="_blank" class="btn">View profile</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          `);
    });

    // if the array returned has fewer people than we requested per page,
    // we've found all the followers. hide the button
    if (followers.length < perPage) {
      $('button').hide();
    }
  });
}

// Make request to Github
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.github.com/users/' + username,
  data: {
    client_id: '9ecc0f206ecd34f2f552',
    client_secret: '6eee17df91630a531ea2acf49848dec408079e9c'
  }
}).done(function(user) {
  // Get first page of followers
  getFollowers(1);
  // Profile HTML
  $('#profile').html(`
        <div>
          <div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <img  src="${user.avatar_url}">
                <div>
              <h3>${user.name}</h3>
            </div>
                <a target="_blank" class="btn" href="${user.html_url}">View Profile</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-9">
              <div>
               <h1>Followers</h1> <br/>
               <p>${user.followers}</p>
              </div>
              <div>
               <h1>Followers</h1> <br/>
               <p>2313123</p>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h3 class="page-header">${user.name}'s followers</h3>
        <div id="followers"></div>
      `);
});
```

```css
#followers {
  counter-reset: users;
}

.col-md-10::before {
  counter-increment: users;
  content: counter(users);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
}

img {
  width: 40px;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1em;
  width: 200px;
}

.row div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="followers"></div>
<button id="load">Load More</button>
<div id="profile"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help Jon! It seems that your solution with a recursive function automatically fetches all followers at one? That's great! Could you help me with a solution that loads the 100 first followers and only loads the next 100 batch when clicking a button? Clicking the button a third time should load the next 100 followers, etc. I put up the complete code on js fiddle if you want to check it out.

https://jsfiddle.net/patrick1904/wcu153ke/

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Patrick1904. Gotcha - I saw this part of your question and missed the bit about a button click: "_I just don't know how to automatically load each new page until there are no more followers to load._" I will modify my answer...

Comment: @Patrick1904 - Okay, I've added a "Load More" button to do as you asked. Let me know if you need any help understanding it.